# CP Subsystem is not enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast with:

- `spring-integration-hazelcast:1.0.0.RELEASE`
- `hazelcast-all:3.12.4`
- see [1] for gradle details

And everything works fine :)

Since I've ran into some problems I tried to update to the latest versions, so:

- `hazelcast 3.12.6`
- and `spring-integration-hazelcast` `2.0.0.RELEASE`

But my application doesn't even start, I'm getting:

```
cluster-manager_1  | com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: CP Subsystem is not enabled!
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftInvocationManager.completeExceptionallyIfCPSubsystemNotAvailable(RaftInvocationManager.java:113)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftInvocationManager.invoke(RaftInvocationManager.java:186)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftService.getGroupInfoForProxy(RaftService.java:752)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.RaftService.createRaftGroupForProxy(RaftService.java:704)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.datastructures.lock.RaftLockService.doCreateProxy(RaftLockService.java:193)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.datastructures.lock.RaftLockService.createProxy(RaftLockService.java:177)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.datastructures.lock.RaftLockService.createProxy(RaftLockService.java:43)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.hazelcast.cp.internal.CPSubsystemImpl.getLock(CPSubsystemImpl.java:76)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.integration.hazelcast.HazelcastLocalInstanceRegistrar.syncConfigurationMultiMap(HazelcastLocalInstanceRegistrar.java:99)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.integration.hazelcast.HazelcastLocalInstanceRegistrar.afterSingletonsInstantiated(HazelcastLocalInstanceRegistrar.java:86)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:896)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
cluster-manager_1  |    at com.btnty.citm.clustermanager.springboot.ClusterManagerApplication.main(ClusterManagerApplication.java:49)
cluster-manager_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
cluster-manager_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
cluster-manager_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
cluster-manager_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
cluster-manager_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

But why? :-( The "problem" is not `hazelcast 3.12.6` because it works with fine
`spring-integration-hazelcast 1.0.0.RELEASE`. But changing from `spring-integration-hazelcast 1.0.0.RELEASE` to `2.0.0.RELEASE` triggers this error.

[1]

```
  implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.5.RELEASE") 
  implementation ("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-hazelcast:1.0.0.RELEASE")
  implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:3.12.4"
  compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-core', version: '5.2.1.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `spring-integration` module uses [Hazelcast CP Subsystem](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#cp-subsystem) (in `CPSubsystemImpl.getLock()`), which is disabled by default in Hazelcast.

You can enable it with the following Hazelcast configuration:

```
@Bean
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getCPSubsystemConfig().setCPMemberCount(3);
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Note that then you should have (at least) 3 Hazelcast members in your cluster.